# Specified unknown buildpack name: "sdk-for-nodejs" In IBM cloud

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

While deploying `Watson` `text-to-speech` instance in `IBM cloud`. I am getting below error.

```
Pushing from manifest to org xx / space dev as xxx...
Using manifest file /workspace/f82d9eab-796e-43c6-89cd-79ccd38c9063/manifest.yml
Getting app info...
Creating app with these attributes...
+ name:         text-to-speech-code-pattern-20210902074058363
  path:         /workspace/f82d9eab-796e-43c6-89cd-79ccd38c9063
  buildpacks:
+   sdk-for-nodejs
+ instances:    1
+ memory:       256M
  services:
+   ttscp-text-to-speech
  routes:
+   text-to-speech-code-pattern-20210902074058363.eu-gb.mybluemix.net

Creating app text-to-speech-code-pattern-20210902074058363...
The app is invalid: Specified unknown buildpack name: "sdk-for-nodejs"
FAILED

Finished: FAILED
```

Below methods i have tried to resolve this issue.

```
1. Have re-created the service instance
2. Have tried to re-create the Delivery Pipeline.
```

But still same error i am getting. Anyone experienced such issue? Please suggest some solution?

Comment: Please add details to your question (not as comment). What is the command you are executing? Is this Cloud Foundry on IBM Cloud? If yes, share the manifest file in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are deploying to Cloud Foundry on IBM Cloud. There was a recent change in IBM Cloud Foundry buildpacks offerings.

> IBM Cloud Foundry provides both an IBM version and an open source version of the Node.js buildpack. To simplify and consolidate around a single Node.js buildpack, IBM is announcing the removal of the IBM version of the Node.js buildpack from the IBM Cloud Foundry service.

You can read more in this [blog](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/announcements/ibm-cloud-foundry-nodejs-buildpack-change). They still support the `nodejs_buildpack` buildpack. You can either change the manifest file or overwrite the buildpack in the delivery pipeline. Additionally, custom buildpacks are still supported.

You can list all the supported buildpacks by using the following command:

```
$ ibmcloud cf buildpacks

Invoking 'cf buildpacks'...

Getting buildpacks...

buildpack                              position   enabled   locked   filename                                             stack
liberty-for-java                       1          true      false    buildpack_liberty-for-java_v3.61-20210826-1015.zip
nodejs_buildpack                       2          true      false    nodejs_buildpack-cflinuxfs3-v1.7.57.zip              cflinuxfs3
noop-buildpack                         3          true      false    noop-buildpack-20140311-1519.zip
xpages_buildpack                       4          true      false    xpages_buildpack_v1.2.2-20170112-1328.zip
staticfile_buildpack                   5          true      false    staticfile_buildpack-cflinuxfs3-v1.5.24.zip          cflinuxfs3
java_buildpack                         6          true      false    java-buildpack-cflinuxfs3-v4.41.zip                  cflinuxfs3
ruby_buildpack                         7          true      false    ruby_buildpack-cflinuxfs3-v1.8.20.zip                cflinuxfs3
go_buildpack                           8          true      false    go_buildpack-cflinuxfs3-v1.9.34.zip                  cflinuxfs3
python_buildpack                       9          true      false    python_buildpack-cflinuxfs3-v1.7.43.zip              cflinuxfs3
php_buildpack                          10         true      false    php_buildpack-cflinuxfs3-v4.4.44.zip                 cflinuxfs3
binary_buildpack                       11         true      false    binary_buildpack-cflinuxfs3-v1.0.39.zip              cflinuxfs3
nginx_buildpack                        12         true      false    nginx_buildpack-cflinuxfs3-v1.1.30.zip               cflinuxfs3
r_buildpack                            13         true      false    r_buildpack-cflinuxfs3-v1.1.20.zip                   cflinuxfs3
dotnet_core_buildpack                  14         true      false    dotnet-core_buildpack-cflinuxfs3-v2.3.32.zip         cflinuxfs3
liberty-for-java_v3_60-20210730-0620   15         true      false    buildpack_liberty-for-java_v3.60-20210730-0620.zip
liberty-for-java_v3_61-20210826-1015   16         true      false    buildpack_liberty-for-java_v3.61-20210826-1015.zip
```